# How to write value to different textfield every time i click a button?

Tags: java, swing, textfield

I am having trouble overcoming this and need your assistance

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guNDa.png)

Every time i click a stop button there is a random number generated in the field above. What I want to do is save each number in the field on the left. Names of the textfields are textField_0, textField_1, textField_2 and so on.

```
izvucen = rnd.nextInt(31) + 1;
randomField.setText(Integer.toString(izvucen)); 
textField_i.setText(Integer.toString(izvucen)); // critical line, need to replace "i" with something
i++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put all text fields in a list when they are created and access them via indexing

```
txtFields.get(i).setText(...)
```

Or put all fields in a map (`Map<Integer, TextField>`) and access specific ones via `get()`

```
mapOfTextFields.get(i).setText()
```

Comment: np. let me know if any problems or if it worked (accept answer or comment etc)